# Object of object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

For reasons I rather not get into the structure of a js script that runs on Java Nashorn inside a Java app now has a different structure.  Because the Java team is not able to convert what was already prior an array of objects it is not coming as object of objects.  The complexity here is that it is nested very far like 5 -6 levels.  Instead of using the a direct approach which I have done for several of the app to convert it, it would be great to find out a way to have a recursive solution.

Here is what the structure can look like as the solution should be agnostic to the key names:

```
  {
   "abc": {
  "items": {
    "0": {
       "cde": "123456",
       "fgh":{
           "0": {"ijk":"987654"}
       }
    },

    ....
It goes on and on.
}

}
}
```

**Sorry for the non-pretty print JSON**

Output expected:

```
  {
   "abc": {
  "items": [
    {
       "cde": "123456",
       "fgh":[{"ijk":"987654"}],

    ....
It goes on and on.
    }

]
}
```

I have been able to use underscore's _.toArray and my own function which I have removed since underscore's solution is perfect.

Any advise?   Any solutions available?   underscore?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want the output to actually look like. But it looks like a JSON representation of nested arrays, which doesn't seem like it should be too difficult to at least get started on--what do you have so far, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: My apologies.    The part where it has "items": { "0":{ ...}} should be an array such as "items":[{"cde":"123456",...}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you getting started.. please read my comments to improve the solution

```
//test object
var json = {
    "abc": {
        "items": {
            "0": {
                "cde": "123456",
                "fgh":{
                    "0": {"ijk":"987654"}
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

//check array: this code should be customized to your needs- I only check for numbers here
var isArray = function (obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object')
        throw new Error('invalid argument');
    for (var m in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(m) && !/^\d+$/.test(m))  //test if key is numeric
        return false;

    return true;
}

//recursive parse-function
var parse = function (obj, node) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object')
        return obj; //break condition for non objects

    if (isArray(obj)) {
        node = node || [];
        for (var m in obj)
            node.push(parse(obj[m]));
    }
    else {
        node = node || {};
        for (var m in obj)
            node[m] = parse(obj[m]);
    }

    return node;
}

//run
var newObj = parse(json);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh4ncbzc/

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfectly for my purpose.   I learned a good amount for this script as the approach was simpler and better than my attempts.